# Create report in txt file with php

Tags: php, file

This script for  write to a file from php :

```
<?php 
$File = "YourFile.txt"; 
$Handle = fopen($File, 'a');
$Data = "Jane Doe\n"; 
fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
$Data = "Bilbo Jones\n"; 
fwrite($Handle, $Data); 
print "Data Added"; 
fclose($Handle); 
?>
```

How to configure align the text like in fpdf (example : `$pdf->Cell(20,10,'Title',1,1,'C');`)  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use str_pad to get a decent result. Say you have 2 rows of data. Like:

Firstname, Lastname

If you want to sort these in a txt file to look nice you can do:

```
$firstname = "Jane";
$lastname = "Doe";

$firstname = str_pad($firstname, 30); //Force string to be 30 characters length
```

str_pad will add an amount of spaces to your string untill it reaches the length you want it to. Having all First names at exactly 30 characters will make the Last names appear perfectly sorted behind them as if you're having 2 lists in your TXT file.

Ofcourse if you ever want to read out the file you probebly want to trim away all those unnessary spaces. You can do this with:

```
$firstname = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $firstname);
```

Comment: How to create new line?

Comment: Use "\n" at the end of your string to create a new line for the next one.